# Wordpress header and footer into a PHP site

Tags: wordpress, themes

I practically have a working sub-directory folder webpage. I would like to have the wordpress header in the page.how can I do this?

example:

main-site/ a wordpress site: butternjam.com 
site that I would like to have wordpress header and footer. : butternjam.com/directory

the files in there are php files how can I implement my wordpress header and footer into this page?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Designing_Headers#The_WordPress_Header
Reading this may help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Make sure that the header and footer are called header.php and footer.php